# npm install (stop process gracefully on preinstall)

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

How can I make `npm install` stop (conditionally) within a preinstall script?

Currently I have a preinstall script `preinstall.js`:

```
if (someCondition) {
  process.kill(process.ppid, 'SIGKILL');
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "preinstall": "node preinstall"
  }
}
```

However this will result in:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

I would like to exit the process gracefully.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "gracefully"? If you intend to prevent the installation, by definition this won't be graceful, and you'll get an "npm ERR!" message

Comment: @Mureinik I indeed intend to prevent installation in certain circumstances. But Netlify needs a succesful exit code in order to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice to preventing the installation of a node package it to return a non-zero exit code from the preinstall script.

You'll still get a bunch of `npm ERR` messages, but it won't kill the npm process like it would with the `process.kill` option you shared, and would get a proper npm log.

I.e., in `preinstall.js`, you could have something like this:

```
if (someCondition) {
    console.error('someCondition happened, aborting installation');
    process.exit(1);
}
```

And when `someCondition` is met, you'll see something like this:

```
$ npm install ~/src/untracked/mypkg/mypkg-1.0.0.tgz

> mypkg@1.0.0 preinstall C:\Users\allon\src\git\samplenode\node_modules\mypkg
> node preinstall

someCondition happened, aborting installation

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mypkg@1.0.0 preinstall: `node preinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mypkg@1.0.0 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/users/mureinik/.npm-cache/_logs/2020-11-29T09_58_46_179Z-debug.log
```

**EDIT:**
Capturing the discussion from the comments in the answer body, so it's easier to find if other encounter the same problem.
The goal here is to fail the installation of a specific package, without failing the entire `npm install` process. This behavior can't be controlled by a preinstall script (that can only control whether the package it's part of successfully installs or not), but can be achieved if the dependency is listed in the [`optionalDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#optionaldependencies) section of the `package.json`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I really need an succesful exit code. I am deploying on Netlify and it won't continue after a succesful install.

Comment: @Tim So you want to prevent the package from installing, but not break the entire npm process? I don't think you can do that with a preinstall script. You could place this package in the `optionalDependencies` section, so its failure to install doesn't break the entire process