# How to error out of `npm install $anything` when there are unstaged changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

In a project that has unsaved changes not commited to git, `npm version patch` will error and complain `Git working directory not clean.` This is good as it avoids publishing a new version that is not in lockstep with a git repo.

I have a similar issue: I would like `npm install ...` to fail if there are unsaved changes (especially when `package.json` has unsaved changes) because only then can I be sure that the most recent changes in my project are all and only about whatever changes the `npm install` command caused.

Is there a way to add such a behavior to `npm`?

**Edit** [npm install (stop process gracefully on preinstall)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058817/npm-install-stop-process-gracefully-on-preinstall) does not address this question. Rather, that post addresses the question how to exit installation of a *particular* package (that the OP controls) under certain circumstances.

What I'd like to have is a *global* configuration where I get this workflow for *all* projects (without the need to configure anything inside those projects):

- `cd my-node-project`
- `npm install whatever`
- if unsaved changes:

  - error `unsaved changes; commit changes and repeat`
- else:

  - `whatever` is installed, `package.json` and `package-lock.json` updated, and *only* these (apart from things in `node_modules`, which is gitignored)
  - `git add . && git commit -m'update dependencies'`
- profit!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install (stop process gracefully on preinstall)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058817/npm-install-stop-process-gracefully-on-preinstall)

Comment: No, that's different. See edit.